# Implement callback in Springboot Java microservices

Tags: spring-boot, rest, callback

**Pre-existing :** Non-UI Java client program invokes REST-based web service API. The request has a callback_url and a unique identifier. Nothing more is known about the client except for the request schema.

**Requirement :** Server is to be developed as Java Springboot microservices exposing CRUD operations in REST APIs.
Server-side: the create request takes a long time to complete. Hence it cannot be synchronous. Upon receiving the request, the server does basic schema validation, starts some asynchronous tasks (like calls to external services or database operations which can take time) and returns response to client.
Whenever the result is available from the async tasks, the server invokes callbackUrl with the result data and status of the operation.

The server is implemented as Springboot webservice using Spring-Web MVC framework.

**Question** : Spawning async tasks in Spring can be done by using Thread Executors and CompletableFuture or by @Async annotation. Which one is recommended?
And when async task is completed, how do I invoke the client API via callback url to return the result data?

Answer (score 1):

I think both CompletableFuture and @Async work well. I prefer @Async because it is more the way Spring works in most of its features.

You can configure the Thread Executor for the @Async with something like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
   @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
}
```

About the second question, I think you can use the spring RestTemplate or WebClient to make the call to the callback_url when the async method finishes.

In both cases, with @Async or Completable Future, you can use the Future class to verify when the processing is done.

```
Future<Object> future = asyncService.asyncMethod();
```

Comment: Is Spring Webflux better in this scenario or the standard Springboot which uses thread pools for scale